# Store cache hit and miss rate calculation in nodejs+mongoose

Tags: node.js, caching

Let me get started with the cache code that i use

```
helper['listAll'] = ()=>{
  return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
    if(cache.get("footer") == null){
      footerModel
        .find({})
        .then((data)=>{
          cache.put("footer",data,parseInt(process.env.CACHE_FOOTER_TIMEOUT));
          fullfill(data);
        })
        .catch((ex)=>{
          reject(ex);
        });
    }else{
      fullfill(cache.get("footer"));
    }
  });
}
```

Now as you can see i need to check how effictive the cache system is on production environment and for that i need the math in hit/miss rate. The data should be accessible via a web console. The problem is that if i keep writing an insert query for each of the hit/miss, it would be more inefficient and there would be no point using cache at all. What is the best possible way that i can go about so that the calculations are stored on the database and also not overload the dbs system ?

The cache model that i am using is `memory-cache` and the last method i tried was set a global counter on hit/miss and a timeout function that pushed the values to redis server every 10 seconds. Is there a better approach that this ?